# PHP universal Database Access

Tags: php, database, security, zend-framework, zend-db

I want my PHP Zend Application to get access to the database.

Because the tasks are only two types: Get and Set a value from the database, I thought about simplifying it with universal methods.

It could look like this example.

```
namespace MyModule\Model;
use Zend\Db\Table\AbstractTable;

class MyTable extends AbstractTable
{
    protected $_name = 'tablename';

    public function getRow($selection)
    {
        $output = array();
        foreach($selection as $key => $value)
        {
            $row = $this->fetchRow($key ' = ' . $value);
            if (!$row) throw new Exception("error");
            array_merge($output, $row->toArray());
        }
        return $output;
    }

    public function addRow($values)
    {
        $this->insert($values);
    }

    public function updateRow($selection, $values)
    {
        foreach($selection as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->update($values, $key ' = ' . $value);
        }
    }

    public function deleteRow($selection)
    {
        foreach($selection as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->delete($key ' = ' . $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any security or design arguments against this methods? I thought about making them global to access database like

```
 $row = database('mydatabase')->table('mytable')->getRow(array('id'=>'5'));
```

This solution would replace all the simple database models.

Comment: You are basically just duplicating the Zend/Db/Table/Abstract class you are extending. This would be really nice if you were writing the Abstract class.If you really want a universal Database access model, you wouldn't extend Zend/Db/Table/Abstract. You would design it to be able to suck data from any Model/DbTable class that already extends Db/Table/Abstract. That way if you ever changed database adapters all you have to do is change your DbTable classes and continue on.

Comment: @RockyFord: That means this is already possible with the default TableAbstract Class?

Comment: That is what the Abstract class does, it provides an interface to give CRUD access to a table. There is a similar class to handle the same functions for a row or rowset. It looks to me like you are trying abstract your data handling in the model. That means you'll have to be fairly careful with data handling in the controller or may encounter sql errors if you have the wrong number of parameters. For example if you use the addRow($values) method and have the wrong number values in your array() you will throw a sql error.

Comment: You are right, I want to abstract my database handeling. I could improve the class above to check the data before inserting/updating/removing. So I shouldn't get sql errors. Are there any security arguments against? How can I get these functionality with the Abstract class out of my controller?

Comment: no security issues I'm aware of, but then I'm no security expert.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I get this functionality with the raw Abstract class from my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll provide a simple example of how Zend_Db works, then you can demonstrate what you intend I'm not sure I completely understand.
The Model

```
// /application/Models/DbTable/MyTable.php
<?php
class Application_Model_DbTable_MyTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    //actual name of database table
    protected $_name = 'My_Table';
    //name of primary key
    protected $_primary = 'id';

}
```

And the controller

```
// /application/controllers/MyController.php
<?php
class Mycontroller extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
}

    public function indexAction() {
        //instantiate DbTable Model and execute FetchAll returns Rowset object
        //call ->toArray() for array to be returned: $model->fetchAll()->toArray();
        $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_MyTable();
        $model->fetchAll();
}
```

with just this simple model all of your CRUD functions are already available to your models and controllers. 
We create new methods or override existing methods to provide more control over our business logic.
 Most of us have need for more then simple CRUD functions.
For example I have a delete function that requires a check for other data to be successful:

```
// /application/Models/DbTable/Track.php
 public function deleteTrack($trackId) {

        $trackRowset = $this->find($trackId);
        $trackToGo = $trackRowset->current();

        $usedBy = $trackToGo->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_DbTable_Member');
        if (count($usedBy) == 0) {

            $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('trackid = ?', $trackId);

            $this->delete($where);
        } else {
            throw new Zend_Exception('Track is still assigned to member(s) and cannot be deleted.'
                . "<br />" . 'Members: ' . count($usedBy));
        }
    }
```

I hope this adds some clarity to our discussion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What I want it do access the database WITHOUT a DbTable file. Just like this (from my Controller): `$row = database('mydatabase')->table('mytable')->getRow(array('id'=>'5'));`
(where the array represents the condition)

Comment: Do you think of the line posted in my comment? No, I don't know how to write the needed functions for that. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: Tell you what check out this free book online by one of the ZF developers, in the models section he really goes into abstracting away unneeded stuff. Once you understand how Zend_Db works I think you'll see why this question is so hard to answer. [Survive the Deepend](http://survivethedeepend.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on the ebook. I will try to write an action helper wich provides basic database support.